# How to use Bing Translation API?

Tags: api, localization, bing, language-translation, microsoft-translator

I am trying to use the Bing Translation API, but I am confused.
There seems to be much possibilities (old and new ones) but I don't understand what I have to do.

Can someone please help me?

I want to send a HTTP Request like `http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId=<AppId>&to=de&text=World` and get the translation. Where to get the AppId?

What I have done so far:

1. Signed in for the free API useage (https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator)
2. Created an App: https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications

Now I have the Client_ID and Client_Secret and also I have a account key (visible here https://datamarket.azure.com/account)

What to do now?

Thanks a lot or any help!

Answer (score 5):

AppID is deprecated. How you need perform following steps:

1. Register you clientID, clientSecter in https://datamarket.azure.com
2. Then you code must getting access token for login BingTranslator API

Read more details instrustions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx

*NB Microsoft Translator has been replaced by Bing Translate, which does not appear to have a readily-available API.*

Comment: https://datamarket.azure.com and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx seems to no longer work.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the links on http://api.microsofttranslator.com. The API takes an access token in the appid parameter. See the section "Obtaining an access token" in the documentation to learn how to get that token.

Comment: I already read through it all, but I have not found a solution... Perhaps I am overseeing something. Also, if I understand the access_token right, you need to create it all x minutes. I want a simple appId which is static and which I can simply hard code into my application ;)

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to use this instructions (if you're using **php**):

**Define your keys**

```
$apis['azure']['id'] = 123456789
$apis['azure']['key'] = 'abcde123456';
```

**Classes and functions**

```
class AccessTokenAuthentication {
    function getTokens($grantType, $scopeUrl, $clientID, $clientSecret, $authUrl){
        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            $paramArr = array (
                'grant_type'    => $grantType,
                'scope'         => $scopeUrl,
                'client_id'     => $clientID,
                'client_secret' => $clientSecret
            );
            $paramArr = http_build_query($paramArr);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paramArr);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $strResponse = curl_exec($ch);
            $curlErrno = curl_errno($ch);
            if($curlErrno){
                $curlError = curl_error($ch);
                throw new Exception($curlError);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            $objResponse = json_decode($strResponse);
            if($objResponse->error){
                throw new Exception($objResponse->error_description);
            }
            return $objResponse->access_token;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception-".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
class HTTPTranslator {
    function curlRequest($url, $authHeader, $postData=''){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authHeader,"Content-Type: text/xml"));
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, False);
        if($postData) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        }
        $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        $curlErrno = curl_errno($ch);
        if ($curlErrno) {
            $curlError = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception($curlError);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $curlResponse;
    }
    function xmlLanguageCodes($languageCodes) {
        $requestXml = '<ArrayOfstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
        if(sizeof($languageCodes) > 0){
            foreach($languageCodes as $codes) {
                $requestXml .= "<string>$codes</string>";
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('$languageCodes array is empty.');
        }
        $requestXml .= '</ArrayOfstring>';
        return $requestXml;
    }

    function xmlTranslateArray($fromLanguage,$toLanguage,$contentType,$inputStrArr) {
        $requestXml = "<TranslateArrayRequest>".
        "<AppId/>".
        "<From>$fromLanguage</From>". 
        "<Options>" .
            "<Category xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" .
            "<ContentType xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\">$contentType</ContentType>" .
            "<ReservedFlags xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" .
            "<State xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" .
            "<Uri xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" .
            "<User xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" .
        "</Options>" .
        "<Texts>";
            foreach ($inputStrArr as $inputStr) {
                $requestXml .= "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">$inputStr</string>";
            }
        $requestXml .= "</Texts>".
        "<To>$toLanguage</To>" .
        "</TranslateArrayRequest>";
        return $requestXml;
    }
}

function get_language_names($locale="en") {
    global $list, $apis;
    try {
        $clientID = $apis['azure']['id'];
        $clientSecret = $apis['azure']['key'];
        $authUrl = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/";
        $scopeUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com";
        $grantType = "client_credentials";
        $authObj = new AccessTokenAuthentication();
        $accessToken = $authObj->getTokens($grantType, $scopeUrl, $clientID, $clientSecret, $authUrl);
        $authHeader = "Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken;
        foreach($list['translate'] as $k=>$iso) {
            $languageCodes[] = $k;
        }
        $url = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetLanguageNames?locale=$locale";
        $translatorObj = new HTTPTranslator();
        $requestXml = $translatorObj->xmlLanguageCodes($languageCodes);
        $curlResponse =$translatorObj->curlRequest($url, $authHeader, $requestXml);
        $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($curlResponse);
        $i=0;
        foreach($xmlObj->string as $language) {
            $result[$languageCodes[$i]] = (string)$language;
            $i++;
        }
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

function get_translate($array, $from, $to, $html=false) {
    global $apis;
    try {
        $clientID = $apis['azure']['id'];
        $clientSecret = $apis['azure']['key'];
        $authUrl = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/";
        $scopeUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com";
        $grantType = "client_credentials";
        $authObj = new AccessTokenAuthentication();
        $accessToken = $authObj->getTokens($grantType, $scopeUrl, $clientID, $clientSecret, $authUrl);
        $authHeader = "Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken;

        $fromLanguage = $from;
        $toLanguage = $to;
        $inputStrArr = array_values($array);
        if($html) {
            $contentType = 'text/html';
            foreach($inputStrArr as $k=>$item) {
                $inputStrArr[$k] = htmlentities($inputStrArr[$k]);
            }
        } else {
            $contentType = 'text/plain';
        }

        $translatorObj = new HTTPTranslator();
        $requestXml = $translatorObj->xmlTranslateArray($fromLanguage,$toLanguage,$contentType,$inputStrArr);
        $translateUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray";
        $curlResponse = $translatorObj->curlRequest($translateUrl, $authHeader, $requestXml);

        $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($curlResponse);
        foreach($xmlObj->TranslateArrayResponse as $translatedArrObj){
            $result[] = (string)$translatedArrObj->TranslatedText;
        }
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

function get_translate_single($input, $from, $to, $html=false) {
    global $apis;
    try {
        $clientID = $apis['azure']['id'];
        $clientSecret = $apis['azure']['key'];
        $authUrl = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/";
        $scopeUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com";
        $grantType = "client_credentials";
        $authObj = new AccessTokenAuthentication();
        $accessToken = $authObj->getTokens($grantType, $scopeUrl, $clientID, $clientSecret, $authUrl);
        $authHeader = "Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken;

        $fromLanguage = $from;
        $toLanguage = $to;
        if($html) {
            $contentType = 'text/html';
            $input = htmlentities($input);
        } else {
            $contentType = 'text/plain';
        }

        # params
        $params = "text=".urlencode($input)."&to=".$toLanguage."&from=".$fromLanguage;
        $translateUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?".$params;

        # object
        $translatorObj = new HTTPTranslator();
        $curlResponse = $translatorObj->curlRequest($translateUrl, $authHeader);

        # interprets a string of XML into an object.
        $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($curlResponse);
        foreach((array)$xmlObj[0] as $val){
            $result = $val;
        }
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**The calls**

```
echo get_translate_single('horse', 'en', 'es'); //this will print 'caballo'
```

or

```
echo get_translate(array('horse', 'house'), 'en', 'es'); //this will print array('caballo', 'casa')
```

That's it, have fun and remember to follow the [terms of service](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator#terms).

Comment: Wow, thanks. this is works bro. But I got this error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$error in {someplace}`

Comment: @HabibRohman try lowering your display error levels: `display_errors(false); error_reporting(0);`

Comment: @FlashThunder I agree, but that's just a quick (and temporal) fix for a dev environment